# code coverage in squish for JAVA

Tags: java, code-coverage, squish

I am using Squish for JAVA. I was wondering whether is it possible to test the code coverage of the Application Under Test(AUT) using Squish(for JAVA). Any help would be much appreciated.

Best regards,
Amal

Answer (score 1):

When using Squish for Java code coverage can be measured with any 3rd party Java coverage tool. With JaCoCo for example. The tools will do their job without knowing about each other.

If you wrap your application in a shell script or batch file simply pass the  -javaagent parameters like described in the [agent setup instructions](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html). After executing your tests via Squish you'll have your coverage data. Possibe output channels are the file system or a network socket.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, other product, from Froglogic, Squish Coco does what you want.
The version you are using, doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You may use JaCoco with Squish.
See Squish's JaCoCo article [here](https://www.froglogic.com/blog/tip-of-the-week/integrating-java-code-coverage-tools-with-squish-tests/).